# Applying a regular expression to a string in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm just getting to know the language R, previously worked with python. The challenge is to replace the last character of each word in the string with *.

How it should look: `example text in string`, and result work: `exampl* tex* i* strin*`

My code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)   

string_example = readline("Enter our text:")
string_example = unlist(strsplit(string_example, ' '))
string_example

result = str_replace(string_example, pattern = "*\b", replacement = "*")
result
```

I get an error:

```
> result = str_replace(string_example, pattern = "*\b", replacement = "*")
Error in stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
  Syntax error in regex pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX, context=``)
```

Help solve the task

Oh, I noticed an error, the pattern should be `.\b`. this is how the code is executed, but there is no replacement in the string

Comment: `str_replace_all("example text in string",". ","* ") %>% str_replace(".$","*")`

Answer (score 5):

If you mean words consisting of letters only, you can use

```r
string_example <- "example text in string"
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(string_example, "\\p{L}\\b", "*")
## => [1] "exampl* tex* i* strin*"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/aEVtfD) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3sIEWY/1).

*Details*:

- `\p{L}` - a Unicode category (propery) class matching any Unicode letter
- `\b` - a word boundary, in this case, it makes sure there is no other word character immediately on the right. It will fails the match if the letter matched with `\p{L}` is immediately followed with a letter, digit or `_` (these are all word chars). If you want to limit this to a letter check, replace `\b` with `(?!\p{L})`.

Note the backslashes are doubled because in regular string literals backslashes are used to form string escape sequences, and thus need escaping themselves to introduce literal backslashes in string literals.

**Some more things to consider**

- If you do not want to change one-letter words, add a non-word boundary at the start, `"\\B\\p{L}\\b"`
- If you want to avoid matching letters that are followed with `-` + another letter (i.e. some compound words), you can add a lookahead check: `"\\p{L}\\b(?!-)"`.

You may combine the lookarounds and (non-)word boundaries as you need.

Comment: Wow, how promptly, thanks, while everything is not very clear to me, maybe I will get used to it over time